# Problems with contenteditable & localstorage with multiple fields

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, contenteditable

I have been trying to solve this with the basic knowledge I have with HTML5, but what I'm trying to do is allow the visitor to edit multiple form fields on one page then save them using localstorage having the ability to see those changes upon re-visiting the page.

This is what I got so far used from from tutorial: http://www.developerdrive.com/2012/06/allowing-users-to-edit-text-content-with-html5/

What is happening is field two is overwriting field one & that is not my expected result. 
Expected result = each editable area should retain it's own edited state after edits are made. There are about 63 fields on the page but for simplicity I have included 2.

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function saveEdits() {

//get the editable element
var editElem = document.getElementById("edit");
var editElem = document.getElementById("edit2");

//get the edited element content
var userVersion = editElem.innerHTML;

//save the content to local storage
localStorage.userEdits = userVersion;

//write a confirmation to the user
document.getElementById("update").innerHTML="Edits saved!";
}

function checkEdits() {

//find out if the user has previously saved edits
if(localStorage.userEdits!=null)
document.getElementById("edit").innerHTML = localStorage.userEdits;
}

</script>
```

HTML:

```
<body onload="checkEdits()">

<div id="edit" contenteditable="true">LASTNAME</div> 
<div id="edit2" contenteditable="true">FIRSTNAME</div>

<input type="button" value="save my edits" onclick="saveEdits()"/>
<div id="update"> - Edit the text and click to save for next time</div>
```

Help would be greatly appreciated especially how and what to add accordingly to include potentially more editable fields in the future.

Comment: what is the purpose of `edit2`?

Comment: @ArunPJohny It's a second form field which allows users to input additional information. Picture a template system - which allows for many things on the page to be edited in-line right on the page.

Comment: It seems to be working fine here http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/b36tH/

Comment: Probably `var editElem = document.getElementById("edit2");` is a typo, you might need `var editElem2 = document.getElementById("edit2");` here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you're overriding the same var editElem twice in your saveEdits() function so you'll get only second one.

If you have a lot of fields, it would be a good idea to store them in one object and save it to localstorage like so:

```
function saveEdits() {
    //get the editable elements.
    var editElems = {
        'edit1': document.getElementById('edit1').innerHTML,
        'edit2': document.getElementById('edit2').innerHTML
    };

    //save the content to local storage. Stringify object as localstorage can only support string values
    localStorage.setItem('userEdits', JSON.stringify(editElems));

    //write a confirmation to the user
    document.getElementById("update").innerHTML="Edits saved!";
}
```

So basically you have an object (editElems) with field id as a key and its value.

Then to retrieve this object and fill your fields on a page:

```
function checkEdits(){
    //find out if the user has previously saved edits
    var userEdits = localStorage.getItem('userEdits');
    if(userEdits){
        userEdits = JSON.parse(userEdits);
        for(var elementId in userEdits){
          document.getElementById(elementId).innerHTML = userEdits[elementId];
        }
    }
}
```

Note that only string values can be stored in localStorage so you'll have to use JSON.stringify when you save an object, then parse it back when you retrieve.

Comment: I've tried your example in a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/stepiiapp/AKz5a/2/ but to no success. I then tried it on my computer and it seems there is no response when the save button is clicked & nothing is saved.

Comment: I'm not sure why it doesn't work on fiddle. Here is a working example on jsbin - http://jsbin.com/aweyag/1

Answer (score 0):

If I understand how you're trying to do this properly, the problem is that you have:

```
var editElem = document.getElementById("edit");
var editElem = document.getElementById("edit2");
```

When you do this, the second line changes the value of `editElem`, so you can no longer use the first value.

I suspect you want to use a for loop:

```
 function saveEdits() {

      for (var i = 0; i < something; i++) {
            // get the editable element
            var editElem = document.getElementById("edit" + i)

            //get the edited element content
            var userVersion = editElem.innerHTML;

            //save the content to local storage
            localStorage.userEdits = userVersion;

      }

      //write a confirmation to the user
      document.getElementById("update").innerHTML="Edits saved!";
 }
```

You'll also have to use distinct keys for each value in local storage, presumably following the same pattern.